# php pdo insert,update into one table in mean time insert query to other table too

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

this is the tables

```
tbl_one
id---int
name-var


tbl_tow
id----int
name--var
```

this is how it will insert with php pdo,

```
public function insert() {  
        $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into tbl_one (name) VALUES (:name)");
        $stmt9->bindParam(':name' ,$this->name);
        $stmt9->execute();
        if($stmt9){
            echo "Added";
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
```

here the idia is to insert in both tables in one time, and delete from both tables in one time.

is it possible here

**NOTE:** i can not use trigger as i have already setup in other case so mysql is not supporting multi trigger in one time or action.

regards

Comment: yes it's kind of history actully the idia is tbl_one will be edit and update but tbl_tow is only insert means each action or transaction will be insert so it will keep the history of any transaction.

Comment: what's the problem if you add an other statement for inserting in the other table !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are looking for a transaction.

All changes performed by queries will be live only when you commit a transaction, if something fails you may simply do a rollback and nothing will happen at all.

This is useful if you have inserts in multiple tables and want to be sure that changes are only made when all queries were a success!

Example:

```
public function insert() {  

    //This will start a transaction and turn-off auto-commit of queries.
    $this->conn->beginTransaction(); 

    $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into tbl_one (name) VALUES (:name)");
    $stmt9->bindParam(':name' ,$this->name);
    $stmt9->execute();

    $stmt10 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into tbl_two (name) VALUES (:name)");
    $stmt10->bindParam(':name' , $someOtherName);
    $stmt10->execute();

    if($stmt9 && $stmt10){
        $this->conn->commit(); //This will save your changes
    } else {
        $this->conn->rollBack(); //This will undo your changes       
    }
}
```

Simple as that.

Comment: is it $dbh->beginTransaction(); or $stmt9->beginTransaction();

Comment: @up: Updated my post. Well you need to use your "PDO" object, however its called I dont know because you are using statement objects here. I dont work that much with PDO extension thatswhy I cant tell for sure but I assume it is stored as $this->conn in your case. See: http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.begintransaction.php

Answer (score 1):

Is this not what you're after?

```
public function insert() {  
    $stmt9 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into tbl_one (name) VALUES (:name)");
    $stmt9->bindParam(':name' ,$this->name);
    $stmt9->execute();

    $stmt10 = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT into tbl_one (name) VALUES (:name)");
    $stmt10->bindParam(':name' ,$this->name);
    $stmt10->execute();
    if($stmt9 && $stmt10){
        echo "Added";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}
```

Basically you double up the queries inside your function, so you can "manually" insert trails to your log table. Sorry if I've misunderstood you.

Comment: This snippet does not rollback the queries if either of them fails.  These are effectively two independent queries being executed.  If `error` is echoed then only one or neither queries were successful.  If only one query was successful, that row is in your database, and the other one is not, and your code doesn't know which one was successful.